# How to restrict user's ssh to non-terminal access without changing /etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

I have a user on my Linux system that is only allowed to use SSH to `scp`, `sftp` and `rsync`, but not allowed to have a shell session in a SSH session. I want to know a secure way to setup the restriction.

A typical answer is to restrict the user's shell, setting in `/etc/passwd` the default shell to `rssh`. However, changing the default shell apparently also affects other applications that depend on the SHELL environment variable. For example, on the latest Fedora 22, it seems to affect the less command, which invokes the default shell, so the user will get a weird warning from `rssh` when he runs the less command (e.g. when being sudoed by another user, not connected through SSH). There could be other programs that are affected in bigger and more dramatic ways.

Setting the user's authorized_keys to restrict the program to run doesn't actually work, because he can use `sftp`/`scp` to change it to something not restrictive.

So, what's another way to restrict the user's access?

Comment: And [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174855/79761) doesn't help you?

Comment: `scp`, `sftp` and `rsync` are quire different tools. You can simply limit to use only `sftp`, but the other two are more complicated since both of them issue normal commands in remote shell.